# Why is my Array returning a partial value?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I am trying to use `textFinder` to return the data from `recordsSheet`; I expect `cslData[0]` to return the employee ID number; however, it is returning the character in the 0 position of the string value.

[image: Results]

```
function textFinder(findID){
  var recordData;
  var findRecord = recordsSheet.createTextFinder(findID);
  var foundRange = findRecord.findNext();
  var fRng = recordsSheet.getRange(foundRange.getRow(),1,1,9)

  while(null != foundRange){
    recordData.push(fRng.getValues());
    foundRange = findRecord.findNext();
  }
  return(recordData);
}
```

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Active Records");

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var eRng = e.range;
  var eRow = eRng.getRow();
  var colA = ss.getRange('A' + eRow).getValue()
      //The second value of the form response (e) is in Column A

  Logger.log("Call txt finder")
  var cslData = textFinder(colA).toString().split(",").join();
  Logger.log("cslData: " + cslData)
  Logger.log("cslData[0]: " + cslData[0])
  Logger.log("cslData[1]: " + cslData[1])
  Logger.log("cslData[2]: " + cslData[2])
  Logger.log("cslData[0][0]: " + cslData[0][0])
}
```

I was expecting `cslData[0]` to return `"100###5"`

Comment: eRow is undefined.  Also the first column in a google form is always a timestamp

Comment: Why bother accessing the sheet when all of the values are in e.values.

Comment: recordSheet is undefined

Comment: @Cooper I edited my question with the corrections. In this case I am looking for data stored on a different sheet to compare to the responses in e.values

Comment: Please add some sample data and more details about how the script is used. (ref. [mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `eRow` is not declared. And, `e` is not used. Please be careful about this. In this modification, it supposes that `eRow` is declared elsewhere.
- In your script, `var recordData;` is not an array. So, I think that an error occurs at `recordData.push(fRng.getValues());`. So, I'm worried that your showing script might be different from your tested script.
- If `var recordData;` is `var recordData; = []`, about your current issue, in your script, the array of `recordData` is converted to the string by `var cslData = textFinder(colA).toString().split(",").join();`. By this, `cslData[0]` returns the top character. I thought that this is the reason for your issue.
- And, if `var recordData;` is `var recordData; = []`, `recordData` is 3 dimensional array.
- In your situation, I thought that `findAll` might be useful.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Active Records");

function textFinder(findID) {
  return recordsSheet
    .createTextFinder(findID)
    .findAll()
    .map(r => recordsSheet.getRange(r.getRow(), 1, 1, 9).getValues()[0]);
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var colA = ss.getRange('A' + eRow).getValue();
  var cslData = textFinder(colA);
  Logger.log("cslData: " + cslData);
  if (cslData.length > 0) Logger.log("cslData[0]: " + cslData[0][0]);
}
```

or, I think that you can also the following script.

```js
function onFormSubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Active Records");
  var eRow = ###; // Please set this.

  var findID = ss.getRange('A' + eRow).getValue();
  var cslData = recordsSheet.createTextFinder(findID).findAll().map(r => recordsSheet.getRange(r.getRow(), 1, 1, 9).getValues()[0]);

  Logger.log("cslData: " + cslData)
  if (cslData.length > 0) Logger.log("cslData[0]: " + cslData[0][0])
}
```

#### Reference:

- [findAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findAll())

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have corrected the missing parts in my post. In this case the form responses stored in `e` are not relevant I only posted the code related to the problem. I am trying your other suggestions and I will respond again.

Comment: @imthatonegirl Thank you for replying. From `In this case the form responses stored in e are not relevant`, for example, in this case, how about testing the script as `var colA = "search value";` instead of `var colA = ss.getRange('A' + eRow).getValue()`? By this, you can directly run the script with the script editor. I thought that the reason for your issue of `however, it is returning the character in the 0 position of the string value.` is due to that the array is being converted to the string value.